# "suggested edit" review test edits are still occuring

Tags: discussion, support

I'm going through suggested edits to review and approve/reject them. I sometimes get the "This edit was a test, you passed" message. I've finished around some 200 edits and never failed these test questions yet, so they're starting to get a little annoying. I take it seriously, spend my time reading the original text and the edit, decide if it should be approved or rejected and then I get this text telling me that it was only a test to see if I was paying attention, which I always do. Will these test questions ever stop? How long will I keep getting them for? It's starting to turning me off reviewing edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will these test questions ever stop?

No, it never ends.

> How long will I keep getting them for?

Currently, until you stop reviewing.

There are a number of other posts on these tests.  They are called "review audits".

Comment: Isn't it possible to have a logic such as: if user's audit pass rate > 90 -> show review audit every 50 reviews, else if user's audit pass rate > 70 -> show review audit every 30 reviews, .. if user's audit review pass rate < 20 -> show review audit every 10 reviews... etc?