# Review audits that require Edit waste the time of the reviewer performing the edit

Tags: discussion, status-norepro, review-queues, review-audits

My question is related to the audits during reviews. I accept value of each audit (to keep attention, correct personal decision algorithm, etc.). However, some time ago in the category **First Posts**, I came across an audit where the **edit** was required as correct answer. I spent some time to putting the code format/question/phrasing together to look good and then I found that the spent time was useless.

Previously I've visited:

- ["suggested edit" review test edits are still occuring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276020/suggested-edit-review-test-edits-are-still-occuring)
- [When, if ever, will I stop getting review audits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260154/when-if-ever-will-i-stop-getting-review-audits)
- ... and some more questions on this topic, not found answer that would clear this up

**Q: For audits where Edit is required and *reviewer* must improve the question, wouldn't it be much more sufficient to stop the test once the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button is pressed?**

---

Edit: I've come accross same situation today and once pressed <kbd>Edit</kbd> button, the review stopped there. But the reasonable act was to **downvote, edit, flag or vote down**. I remember the issued behavior above from some time before. So if it was implement/cleared out for all the queues, please confirm that too.

[image: Working example]

Comment: I've never had that happen.

Comment: No matter what queue you're in, "skip" is always an acceptable response, FWIW. Audit or otherwise.

Comment: @TylerH I agree, but if You don't recognize that the edited topic is audit, you are going to edit it anyway.

Comment: I've already _failed_ audits when I tried to remove spam links from spam answers.. but I failed as soon as I failed the audit. It was in low quality posts queue, though

Comment: When you select "Edit" from a review task and complete the edit, the review of that post is considered complete and the post is removed from the review queue. So, you should ***only** select "edit" as your review action when you can resolve all reasons for the post being in the review queue.* If you can't *resolve all issues* that the post has, then you should not select "edit" from review. If what you are doing is merely partially cleaning up the post, then open the post in a new tab and edit it from there, *not from review*.

Comment: Review audits t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶i̶r̶e̶ ̶E̶d̶i̶t waste the time of the reviewer p̶e̶r̶f̶o̶r̶m̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶e̶d̶i̶t. They're one of the major reasons I never really got into using the review queues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A correct review audit will *not* require editing. It will require downvoting, flagging, and/or deletion.

Under no circumstances should you be editing non-answers or garbage posts (a more complete guide to reviewing can be found [here in the Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)). There is no way to solve the problems with these posts via editing. The posts you're seeing as audits have such fundamental problems that they need to be deleted outright, not polished.

I don't know if you intended the screenshot you showed as an example of a post that needs to be edited, but it doesn't. It needs to be deleted. Yes, the use of blockquote formatting is incorrect there. But fixing the formatting is not going to save that answer. Unless you're going to take the time to expand it into a complete answer, showing how the linked library actually solves the problem in the question, you should not be editing it. Instead, you should be flagging it as "not an answer" so that it can be deleted.

Therefore, I disagree with your proposal here. In fact, on a valid review audit, selecting the "Edit" option should probably cause you to fail the audit. Why fail? Because editing a post that needs to be flagged and/or deleted actually *causes harm*—it removes the post from the review queue, preventing anyone else from seeing it and taking the appropriate action on it. Therefore, to the extent that review audits are testing whether reviewers are taking the appropriate actions, they need to ensure that you are not choosing to edit unsalvageable posts.

If the problem is that you're seeing posts salvageable via editing as review audits, then the problem is that we have badly chosen review audits. A better way to fix that would be to allow moderators to nominate/curate posts that are used as review audits.

Answer (score 8):

As you observed after first posting this, "edit" should complete the review immediately - it should never actually *let you edit the post*. If it does, then either the review task isn't an audit... Or there's a bug.

I've not been able to reproduce such a bug in my testing, but if you encounter it again please let me know.

See also: [Your review was inappropriate - sorry, but it wasn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368048/your-review-was-inappropriate-sorry-but-it-wasnt/368118#368118)

Answer (score 1):

> For audits where Edit is required and reviewer must improve the question, wouldn't it be much more sufficient to stop the test once the Edit button is pressed?

Undoubtedly, yes it would.